# Undefined reference to sem_init and other such functions even though -lpthread and -ltr are used

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

This is my code for reader writer problem in c in linux.
I saw some same previous questions and the solution to them was using -lpthread or -ltr, I tried those two both individually and together but still I am getting the same error continuously. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

sem_t rmutex,wmutex,canwrite;
int readcount=0;

void *reader1(int i)
{
printf("Reader %d wants to read\n",i);
sem_wait(&rmutex);
readcount++; 
sem_post(&rmutex); 
printf("Reader %d is reading",i);

sem_wait(&rmutex);
readcount--;

if(readcount==0) 
sem_post(&canwrite);

sem_post(&rmutex);
printf("Reader %d is exiting",i);

}

void *writer1(int i)
{
printf("Writer wants to write\n");
sem_wait(&canwrite);
sem_wait(&wmutex);
printf("Writer is writing\n");
sem_post(&wmutex);
printf("Writer is exiting\n");
}



int main()
{
pthread_t *reader[3],*writer;
int i;
sem_init(&rmutex,0,1);
sem_init(&wmutex,0,1);
sem_init(&canwrite,0,1);


pthread_create(&writer,NULL,writer1,(void *)i);
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
pthread_create(&(reader[i]),NULL,reader1,(void *)i);

sleep(10000);

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
pthread_join(reader[i],NULL);

pthread_join(writer[i],NULL);

return 0;
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
vineet@vineet-TravelMate-P643-M:~/Work$ cc -lpthread rw.c
rw.c: In function ‘main’:
rw.c:49:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type     [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘pthread_t * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘pthread_t **’
 rw.c:49:1: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of    type ‘void * (*)(int)’
rw.c:51:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘pthread_t * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘pthread_t **’
rw.c:51:1: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of  type ‘void * (*)(int)’
rw.c:56:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_join’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:242:12: note: expected ‘pthread_t’ but argument is of type  ‘pthread_t *’
/tmp/ccYZOwcD.o: In function `reader1':
rw.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
rw.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `sem_post'
rw.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
rw.c:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `sem_post'
rw.c:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `sem_post'
/tmp/ccYZOwcD.o: In function `writer1':
rw.c:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
rw.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
rw.c:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `sem_post'
/tmp/ccYZOwcD.o: In function `main':
rw.c:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `sem_init'
rw.c:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `sem_init'
rw.c:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `sem_init'
rw.c:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
rw.c:(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
rw.c:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
rw.c:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And it would be really helpful if you could also explain the warning.

Comment: I think you should edit your post and correct code formatting.

Comment: @rtruszk I didn't understand what you are trying to suggest.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: your code never got beyond the compile stage, so you can ignore the linker error statements, for now.  Fix the compile problems first, then worry about any linker problems.

Comment: this line: cc -lpthread rw.c would be much better written as: cc rw.c -o rw.o -I. -I/usr/include -lpthread -lclib6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues with this.

First, instead of using `pthread_t *` for your variable types, you should only use `pthread_t` (i.e., not a pointer). This is what the warnings refer to.

Second, the reason you're getting those linker errors is because the order in which you specify input files and linker options on the command line matters. Since `rw.c` depends on `-lpthread`, the `-lpthread` option should come *after* `rw.c`, not before:

```
cc rw.c -lpthread
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Any idea how can i make a thread execute a function again and again, Should i just keep re-initializing it??

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.